# generating random values in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, random

I have used rand(). But it gives a specific value even after I restart application.

I have implemented following in my application.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
int x,y;

x=random() % 480; y=random() % 300;

lblT.center=CGPointMake(x,y); // my label lblT
}
```

Try to implement in your application, and launch application.
After restarting application, you will find that label will be on specific value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`arc4random()` is a built-in function that does not require seeding (and so therefore does not produce predictable sequences that can be generated by using a seed), and it conveniently returns integers.  I never use anything else.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following line before random()

`srand(time(NULL));`

Answer (score 2):

Random number generators in software will actually give PSEUDORANDOM sequences of values.

Unless you seed the random number generator with a value from a truly random event, you will always get the same sequence each time you use the software.

I don't know about your software, but it doesn't look like you're seeding the random number generator, [Gcamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111783/gcamp) is probably on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using **random()** and not **rand()** you should seed the random generator with this bit of code...

`srandomdev();`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

landscape:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


int x = arc4random()%480;
int y = arc4random()%320;

lblT.center=CGPointMake(x,y);
}
```

not landscape:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    int x = arc4random()%320;
    int y = arc4random()%480;

    lblT.center=CGPointMake(x,y);
    }
```

Comment: you can use arc4random_uniform(value); instead of mod operator

Answer (score 1):

use this code, only for **Integer** random values

```
#define random(min,max) ((arc4random() % (max-min+1)) + min)
```

testing

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    NSLog(@"rand is %d", random(-100,100));
}
```