# Trying to generate random numbers on iphone, get same number

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make a card game.  I'm using the following code to draw a random card

iCard=random() % 55;

but icard is always starts out with 28.
Seems like it gives back the numbers in the same order.

is there a way to get a diffrent random number each time the function is first called????

Comment: Sanford has a class on iOS development, the first project is a card game. It might help you out. http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449754/iphone-random-function-gives-me-the-same-random-number-everytime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random()` and `rand()` uses a seed and it is always the same seed sequence.

Use `arc4random()` it uses no seed and is 100% random

Comment: Use `arc4random_uniform(X)` instead of `arc4random() % X`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code: `int random = min + arc4random() % (max - min + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IMCard*) drawRandomCard
{
    IMCard *randomCard = nil;

    if ([self.cards count]) {
        unsigned index = arc4random() % [self.cards count];
        randomCard = self.cards[index];
        [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }


    return randomCard;
 }
```

Comment: You should use arc4random_uniform([self.cards count]) to avoid a modulo bias