# Requiring many random numbers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to create a mastermind style game to build up my iOS objective c skills.  I'm trying to create 6 random numbers between 0 and 9 using the following.   I get different numbers when run at different times but all 6 numbers are always the same on each run.

```
NSNumber *n1 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:(random() % 10)];
NSNumber *n2 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:(random() % 10)];
NSNumber *n3 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:(random() % 10)];
NSNumber *n4 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:(random() % 10)];
NSNumber *n5 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:(random() % 10)];
NSNumber *n6 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:(random() % 10)];
```

Any help would be very useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436217/generating-random-values-in-iphone) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449754/iphone-random-function-gives-me-the-same-random-number-everytime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to seed the random generator(i.e. add the following line before generating random numbers):

```
srandom(time(NULL));
```

Anyway, on iPhone you should use arc4random() function - it provides much better results and does not require seeding:

```
NSNumber *n1 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:(arc4random() % 10)];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Turned out it was me being a muppet.  Getting the numbers back out of an array for an alert, I forgot to change the index.