# Runtime Random Generators, not Compile Time

Tags: objective-c, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone: random() function gives me the same random number everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449754/iphone-random-function-gives-me-the-same-random-number-everytime)

I am writing a test iPhone app for a larger project that I am working on that will involve randomized strings, numbers, etc.  When I use the `rand()` or `random()` functions, every single time I do get randomized numbers and strings, but in the same order! I know that the compiler determines the order at compile time, but do not want that.  I want it to be completely random, so something different every time not just a predetermined list.  What I have tried is a loop that counts up and down to try to take a value from that but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to change the seed value?  Perhaps you should read up on random number generators and seeds.  Then you might be able to clarify your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: random() function gives me the same random number everytime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449754/iphone-random-function-gives-me-the-same-random-number-everytime) plus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436217/generating-random-values-in-iphone

Comment: What do you want to use them for? The quality of the PRNG you require depends heavily on that.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't generate the random strings; they're generated at runtime. But they are generated based on an initial *seed*; for a given value of the seed, you'll get the same sequence of numbers. You need to choose a seed at runtime based on something like the system time, uptime, count of user clicks, etc.

Comment: so would I do better with arc4random()?

Comment: oh and sorry I meant the numbers are determined at runtime not compile time

Comment: Yes, I believed `arc4random()` is self-seeding.

Comment: Yep, `arc4random` worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You need to seed the number for rand. This way it will be random every time!

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
// Seed number for rand() 
srand((unsigned int) time(0) + getpid());
```

Add the above line of code before using rand()

Answer (score 1):

Random number generators are never truly "random," and instead generate a number based on something that should always be different.  Giving a random number generator a unique value so that it can generate a random number is know as "seeding." For `rand()`, you will want to seed it with `srand(time(NULL))`.  For `random()` it's the same deal with `srandom()`. There are functions available for iOS such as `arc4random()`, which is self-seeding.  To generate a random number up to (but not including) 10, for instance, you could use `arc4random()` as follows:

```
int random = arc4random() % 10;
```